# Will standard deadbolts and door knobs work on a 7/8" thick security door?

Tags: doors, security, doorknob, deadbolt

This will be my first time replacing deadbolts and door knobs, and I want to make sure I get the right size.

The distance between the edge of the door and the center of the deadbolt I need to replace is 2 3/8". And the space between the deadbolt and the door knob is 5/8".

Comment: What is the door made out of?  7/8 wood why bother with locking it, a poor kick will just open it anyway.  Most knobs will have the size they are made for marked on their labelling.  I would like to know more about the 5/8 distance.

Comment: It's a security door, and it's made of metal - wrought iron. So I don't see anyone kicking it in.

Comment: The 5/8" distance is the space between the bottom of the deadbolt and the top of the door knob plate.

Comment: I believe you need to look at iron gate locks.  Probably go to a locksmith shop.

Comment: If it's really "wrought iron", rather than the more typical steel security door, then I agree you may need to be talking to folks who work with gates rather than doors unless a lock box compatible with more common locks has already been designed and built into it. (I'm guessing that's a misstatement, though.)

Comment: A picture would be very helpful here.

Comment: Could always use a metal plate or two to create some thickness.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is likely no. Most modern locksets are standardized for 1-3/8" interior and 1-3/4" exterior door thicknesses, with some tolerance for variation from those dimensions. 7/8" is far enough from standard that they're unlikely to work.

The main problem is the skirt of the unit, which surrounds the mechanism. It's likely more than 7/8" deep, so you'd have to heavily modify it to make it work. The actuator shaft would also probably need to be shortened.

Your best bet might be to install bored shim plates on each side of the door. 1/4" twice would get you to 1-3/8", so you'd be all set.

Comment: Aren't most "wrought iron" security doors fitted with expensive mortise locks and special locks?

Comment: Yes, but we don't really know what we're dealing with. I'm responding to the question as posed.